# How to Display SVGs in Julia?

Tags: xml, user-interface, svg, julia

I am creating SVG files using Luxor.jl. I want to display them in a live window, 1 by 1, at 60 fps. I dont want to render out the images as an mp4. I just want to display them in a window, and keep updating the image source every fraction of a second. How do I do that? (I am hoping for the most efficient way out)

I looked up Image.jl, ImageShow and a bunch of other stuff. Didn't seem to help. Maybe I'm missing something? And yes, I want to use the REPL, not the Jupyter notebook!
please help.

Comment: Try using `Pluto.jl` and rendering the SVG dby directly injecting it into browser. This is not a full answer, but it is where I would go.

Comment: Not a big fan of notebooks ...

Comment: @Maddy Pluto is far superior to Jupyter. It solves the whole issue of state dependency by evaluating cells reactively.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Luxor to render GIF and then Electron to display it.

```
using Luxor

function make_an_svg(i)
    cols = ["#389826", "#cb3c33", "#9558b2"]
    return """
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <circle fill="$(cols[i % 3 + 1])" cx="256" cy="137" r="$((i % 3 + 1)*3 + 80)"/>
    <circle fill="$(cols[(i+1) % 3 + 1])" cx="145" cy="329" r="$((i % 3 + 2)*3 + 80)"/>
    <circle fill="$(cols[(i+2) % 3 + 1])" cx="367" cy="329" r="$((i % 3 + 3)*3 + 80)"/></svg>"""
end 
function frame(scene, framenumber)
    background("black")
    placeimage(readsvg(make_an_svg(framenumber)), O, centered=true)
end
movie = Movie(430, 430, "my movie", 1:20)
gif_name = animate(movie, [Scene(movie, frame, 1:20)], framerate=4, creategif=true)

using Electron, URIs
app = Application()
win = Window(app, URI("file://$(replace(gif_name.filename,'\\'=>'/'))"))
```

[image]

Credits for this GIF generation code:  https://discourse.julialang.org/t/svg-to-rgb-how-to-save-a-series-of-svg-images-to-video/85309/4

Comment: Ammm I don't want to render it out as a GIF or MP4. But yeah, I figured Electron was the way to go to render out svgs one by one. Perhaps I can use Blink.jl?

Comment: Electron keeps inside an HTML browser, so I guess you would need to program your animation in JavaScript and then submit it to Electron for rendering.

Comment: Say I have 5 svg files names file1.svg, file2.svg... file5.svg. Can I somehow use Blink(Electron wrapper for Julia) or anything else for that matter to display file1.svg. The  after 0.2 seconds, display file2.svg and so on... I really don't want to create an MP4 or GIF as I am actually creating a simulation so actually I'm generating the svgs side by side! They are not generated in advance!

Comment: I think that the page refresh would take too long. I would write a Julia code that generates a JavaScript code and than let Electron run this JavaScritpt code (Electron is just a web browser so this would be no problem). The JavaScript code would contain all svg frames so you should get a nice animation.

Comment: Perhaps 'animate' could write to an `IOBuffer`. In that case you could also write a very simple a webservice that emits the gif file and redirect Electron to that service - in that case no file would be written to the disk

Comment: Dude!!! I found a way out!!!
I just created an index.html file. I linked an SVG file into the body. Opened it in a live server, thanks to VS Code. I can just update the data in the SVG file through the same processes I used to create SVGs in the first place (I made 450 of them each second).

Now, please do me a last favour man... Tell me the Live server copes with the changes as fast as that. I mean can I at least get it to work at 60fps?

Again, Thanks for all the help dude... You're amazing!

Comment: You would need to try to set `liveServer.settings.wait` option for a value as low as possible. However, I would expect it takes around 50ms-100ms to reload the page so it might be hard to get 60fps (and BTW how are you going to check whether you actually have 60fps).

Comment: I got no idea about that. ☹️
Ahhhh why can't I get to play a sequence of svg's one after the other!!??

All right how do you propose I do it?


I'm creating svg's using Luxor. HOW DO I GET THEM TO PLAY ONE BY ONE!? (without creating a gif or mp4 simply because I can't. I won't have enough time to render out media as mp4 or gif as I GENERATING svgs alongside the playback.)

Comment: I told you - you need to program that in JavaScript, place that JavaScript in index.html and run that page in Electron.